# Как подключить библиотеку cryptopp с использованием cmake linux?

Tags: linux, cmake, библиотеки, clion

Я установил библиотеку с помощью команды

```
make install
```

В cryptopp по пути */usr/local/include/cryptopp/* находятся только заголовочные файлы.

В cmake файле проекта сейчас находятся данные строки:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(cryptopp REQUIRED)
add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cryptopp" with any
  of the following names:

    cryptoppConfig.cmake
    cryptopp-config.cmake
```

Использую clion на ubuntu.

Студия видит библиотеку. В include появляются подсказки с названием библиотеки. У меня почти нет опыта в использовании cmake я не понимаю как можно её прилинковать к проекту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данная библиотека не предоставляет cmake файла, то его нужно написать самому или просто написать несколько строк для этого.

Но если чуточку поискать, то можно найти готовое https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake

Инструкция там простая - они прелагают скопировать пару файлов с их репозитория

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
cd cryptopp

wget -O CMakeLists.txt https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake/master/CMakeLists.txt
wget -O cryptopp-config.cmake https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake/master/cryptopp-config.cmake
```

То, что Вы пользуетесь CLion, в данном случае скорее всего не важно, но если сам CLion не сможет, то я бы порекомендовал попробовать с консоли собрать.